# Is it a good idea to use either the rinkeby or ropsten test networks for a smart contract others have to access?

Tags: testing, ethereum, smartcontracts

The reason why I want to do that, is because other people should be able to buy my token without actually having to spend any real money (if I did it on the live network they would have to pay the transaction fees at least, correct me if I'm wrong). Answers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ropsten is a perfect test net and will allow as many people you need to access it for how ever long you need.

Comment: @scroperationX if this answer was correct, please mark it as correct so future readers know this has been solved.

Comment: Actually it doesn't really answer the question, sorry.

Comment: Then can you clarify what your question is? You asked if it is a good idea to use Rinkeby or Ropsten for a smart contract for others to have access to. I guess I didn't answer the last part, either will give access the same way but I would go with Ropsten due to the other benefits.

Comment: My question was aimed toward whether it is a idea to use ropsten for a contract that around 15 people have to use for a few weeks or whether there might be any issues the live blockchain would not have. My reason to use the test chains is to keep the system free to use for the users and myself (creator of the token).

Comment: Ok. There would be no issues by not using the main net that you should encounter. It is the same but the Ether is "fake".

Comment: Well I can live with that since the whole thing is for educational purposes only... So unless Ropsten gets resettet within that time I'm good, otherwise... I'm screwed

Comment: It will not be reset, don't worry. I have been testing on a contract for over a year with no issues. Over 200 people testing. I will update my answer as well. If you think it is the right answer, please mark it as correct and upvote.